# Delete object from internal method / Or delete from pointer (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Apparently this is not possible

```
function node(){
  this.value="hello";
  var self = this;

  this.remove=function(){
    delete(self); //no found
       //or
    self=null;  //no found
  }
}

var test = new node();
test.remove(); //no found
```

---

This only removes the pointer, this does not delete the pointed object

```
var test = new node();
var aux = test;
delete aux;
```

---

This only removes the pointer, this does not delete the pointed object

```
var test = new node();
var aux = test;
aux=null;
```

Comment: test is global (on the window object in a browser) ... `delete window.test` ... not sure how you could do it within the object itself though, nor if `test` was a var within a function ... but once a function completes, the GC would remove it if possible

Comment: You cannot delete/deallocate objects in JavaScript. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `aux = null` replaces the value, it doesn't "*remove the pointer*". The *delete* operator only deletes object properties. *self* is a variable, they can't be deleted (they are conceptually properties of an [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts), but not actual properties).